# Changing maxvalue of sequence which is defined inside table in db2

Tags: db2, sequence

Hi I want to Change maxvalue of sequence which is defined inside table in db2.

Alter sequence "sequencename" is not working

Alter sequence is not working

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?  What does "not working" mean?  Are you getting an error message?  What is it?

Answer (score 1):

A Sequence is external to a table.

Are you actually trying to update an identity column?

[ALTER TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-alter-table) *MY_TABLE* ALTER COLUMN *MYCOLUMN* SET MAXVALUE *MY_MAX_VALUE*